# I want Spy++ but I don't have Visual Studio

Tags: .net, spy++

I only have SQL Server 2008 Client tools. I would like to use [Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242713%28VS.60,printer%29.aspx), but of course, it only comes with the Visual Studio installation.

Is there a good replacement for Spy++ that I can use?

Comment: btw, for WPF apps use Snoop for WPF and for WPF/Silverlight/etc. you can use XAML Spy (formerly Silverlight Spy)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Winspector](http://web.archive.org/web/20090916053057/http://www.windows-spy.com/) has been more helpful. Not sure why their site is down right now, but there are a lot of other places to download it.

Comment: You can still get it here: http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Security-Related/Winspector.shtml

Comment: It seems not to work on a 64 bit Operating System :(

Comment: More specifically, it works on 64 bit Windows but doesn't seem to support 64bit apps

Comment: Not capturing for me on windows 10

Comment: @hamboy75 out of curiosity, were you running it as admin?

Comment: yes :(. spyxx14.rar worked for me.

Comment: https://www.filedropper.com/processing/filedownload.php?id=spyxx14

Answer (score 38):

There is [WinSpy++](http://www.catch22.net/software/winspy) by James Brown at Catch22.net

However, the software downloaded from the site as of today (Jan 2023) gets blocked by smartscreen and malware filters.  It also only works for 32bit apps if you ignore all that and install anyway.

Comment: Does not seem to have any way to log messages, making it next to useless.

Comment: Does have a crosshair though you can drop on UI elements to select them which is handy

Comment: Firefox reports the downloads from this site as an 'Unwanted Software Page'

Comment: @pepgma Ditto in Chrome (https://www.google.com/transparencyreport/safebrowsing/diagnostic/index.html?hl=en-US#url=http://www.catch22.net/sites/default/files/WinSpy17.zip).

Answer (score 20):

Visual Studio 2013 now has a [community edition](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs).  See the Q&A on that page to see if you can use it.

Spy++ is included in the community edition.  I had to launch the "Developer Command Prompt for VS2013" and then run the spyxx.exe executable from that command prompt.  Searching for "spy++" or "spyxx" in the "Search programs and files" entry box on the (Windows 7) start menu didn't find it.

Comment: I see Spy++ at ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\spyxx.exe" (32-bit) and "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\spyxx_amd64.exe" (64-bit). Both seem to be installed under c:\Program Files (x86), but that location is probably cause Visual Studio is 32-bit itself

Comment: Hmm, that didn't get installed for me; I guess it's in an optional component that I didn't ask for?

Comment: Oh. It looks like I have "express" (for windows desktop), not "community". That's not confusing at all ...

Answer (score 18):

just download from:

> http://mdb-blog.blogspot.com/2010/11/microsoft-spy-or-spyxx-for-download.html

it contains versions:

- 7.0
- 8.0
- 10.0
- 11.00
- and 14.00 (latest)

Comment: This seems to now be the latest: http://mdb-blog.blogspot.com/2017/02/download-microsoft-spy-140-2016-06-20.html

Comment: However, the above download does not include the mfc140u.dll C++ redistributable from Visual Studio.  You can download that as a standalone from here: https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?pid=2082 though you'll need to opt into the Visual Studios Dev Essentials program for free.

Comment: Also https://github.com/westoncampbell/SpyPlusPlus.

Answer (score 9):

A very decent effort to revive the beloved but defunct winspector is window detective : http://windowdetective.sourceforge.net/

Comment: No 64 bit build available for capturing messages from 64 bit applications.

Answer (score 4):

[**Visual UI Automation Verify**](http://www.codeplex.com/UIAutomationVerify)

> With the Visual UIA Verify, you can quickly find and select any UI element anywhere on the desktop. Based on the specific control type and the supported control patterns, UIA Verify provides the built-in test scenarios prioritized for the particular UI element. Developers can add additional test scenarios by adding the code to the UIA Test Library. The tool can output the test results or the summary in various forms. Visual UIA Verify can output test details in HTML.

Answer (score 3):

The free download for windows SDK includes UISpy... is that close enough?

Answer (score 3):

I think WinSpy++ looks like the best bet, especially since it ships with source and is compatible with Vista (Win7 too presumably).

However, the first clone I'd run across was [WinID](http://www.dennisbabkin.com/php/download.php?what=WinID).  No source and claims not to support Vista, but it may do some things WinSpy++ doesn't...like extracting icons and fonts ("Capture Shot").

*Note: tried to post this as a comment and not an answer, but the link wouldn't work.*

Answer (score 2):

I just used Windows Detective. Worth taking a look:

http://windowdetective.sourceforge.net/

Comment: No support for 64-bit processes. A 2017 build x_x

Answer (score 0):

Try using HWndSpy.
Source code is [here](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/481837/196972).

[image]