# Win32 Messages program

Tags: winapi

Few years ago when I was doing win32 programming, there was a program (from Microsoft I believe) that helps see all messages sent to winproc real time. I think it's a dialog box with all controls and depending of the actions you do, it display messages sent to that control.

Does anyone know which program I am talking about? If so what's the name and where can I find it. Thank you.

Comment: It's not spy++. It's was a different program.

Comment: Are you sure? Can you describe it?

Comment: yes I am sure because I know spy++. If I remember well, it's simple window on which you have common window controls. When you select a control, it appears somewhere in the dialog and you could interact with it. While you interact with it, you see all messages triggered real time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program you are looking for is [Control Spy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773165(VS.85).aspx).

As others have mentioned there is also Spy++.  Source is available for a Spy++-like program called [WinSpy++](http://www.catch22.net/software/winspy).  (More alternatives on the thread [i-want-spy-but-i-dont-have-visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811019/i-want-spy-but-i-dont-have-visual-studio))

Comment: I have Visual studio installed on my computer and just and I know spy++. but it's not the program that I am looking for :(

Comment: Oh.  Control Spy, then.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773165(VS.85).aspx

Comment: YES! that's the program I have been looking for :) Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

is it [spy++](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2007/01/16/spy-internals.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's called Spy++.

It comes with Visual Studio, and you can find it in under Start, Programs, Microsoft Visual Studio 20*xx*, Visual Studio Tools.