# How to send WM_APPCOMMAND message

Tags: c#, sendmessage, user32

I'm trying to send [WM_APPCOMMAND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message to foreground window, but it's not working.
Can someone explain to me how to do it correctly?

```
[DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int GetForegroundWindow();

public const int WM_APPCOMMAND = 0x319;
public const int APPCOMMAND_UNDO = 34;

SendMessage(GetForegroundWindow(), WM_APPCOMMAND, 0, WM_UNDO * 65536);
```

**EDIT:**
Hans Passant: Most AppCommands are mapped to dedicated keys on the keyboard and automatically triggered when you press such a key. Since very few keyboards actually have an Undo key, the odds that an app will respond to APPCOMMAND_UNDO are zilch.

Thank you Hans. This is the answer.

Comment: Define 'not working'. Also, did you check the results of GetForegroundWindow to see if you get a handle? And if so, if it is the right handle? Maybe you can use one of the [tools mentioned in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423869/wincheat-winspy-like-tool-for-c-builder-exes) to help you check that.

Comment: It's not doing "Undo" in foreground window... I also have this code: SendMessage(GetForegroundWindow(), WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MINIMIZE, 0); and it's working, so I suppose GetForegroundWindow() is returning right handle.

Comment: Are you sure you've got the right value for WM_UNDO? Says it is 0x304 in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761693%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Sorry, I meant APPCOMMAND_UNDO: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#appcommand_undo
Yes, the value is 34... I was following this tutorial: https://kalshagar.wikispaces.com/Remote+controlling+Windows+media+player+in+C

Comment: It's not guaranteed that every application will implement that message. There is no rule that states that it should.

Comment: Most AppCommands are mapped to dedicated keys on the keyboard and automatically triggered when you press such a key.  Since very few keyboards actually have an Undo key, the odds that an app will respond to APPCOMMAND_UNDO are zilch.