# Is there a tool to know if a program is requesting WM_INPUT events?

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, input

WM_INPUT events are the raw input events that windows translates directly from each device. E.g. you get a message with raw mouse deltas from each mouse you have plugged, instead of the windows cursor position that you get with the normal input events. A program has to register a callback, in order to receive those events.

I would like to know if a program, e.g. a videogame, has requested to get those events. A powershell script or bat would be fine.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-input

Answer (score 0):

There're apps out there that can give this to you, I believe a popular albeit old one had something with 'spy' in the name. Vs also seems to have something integrated which is called Spy++.

Also Inspect;
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Windows internals suite could also help, like procmon;
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Here's a better list with some options:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2425315/4122889