# Win forms, log all clicks?

Tags: winforms, logging

Is there a way to log all of the clicks in a Win Forms application?  I'd like to intercept clicks and record the action and the name of the control that caused it.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I'm looking for an application wide solution, is there no way to add a listener to the windows event queue (or what ever it is called)?

Comment: create a new class that derives form class, then put David Fox's code in your new class.  on consumer form, inherit from your new class instead of default Form.  public class Form1 : MagicForm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by having your app's main form implement the IMessageFilter interface.  You can screen the Window messages it gets and look for clicks.  For example:

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form, IMessageFilter {
    public Form1() {
      InitializeComponent();
      Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
      this.FormClosed += (o, e) => Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
    }

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m) {
      if (m.Msg == 0x201 || m.Msg == 0x203) {  // Trap left click + double-click
        string name = "Unknown";
        Control ctl = Control.FromHandle(m.HWnd);
        if (ctl != null) name = ctl.Name;
        Point pos = new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32());
        Console.WriteLine("Click {0} at {1}", name, pos);
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Note that this logs *all* clicks in any window of your app.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.  I'd seen Application.AddMessageFilter but had no idea how to get a control from a handle.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Spy++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811019/i-want-spy-but-i-dont-have-visual-studio) or [WinSpy++](http://www.catch22.net/software/winspy) to achieve this.

[alt text http://www.catch22.net/sites/default/files/images/winspy1.img_assist_custom.jpg](http://www.catch22.net/sites/default/files/images/winspy1.img_assist_custom.jpg)

But I'm not sure how you can achieve the same thing yourself. If it's possible you'd need to do it via a low-level Windows API hook or a message handler that gives you access to all the message in your applications queue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could subscribe to the `Click` or `MouseDown` event of every control on the form.

Comment: obviously, but I'm looking for something that takes care of this as a cross cutting concern. In a large application this approach just isn't feasible.

Answer (score 0):

use MouseEventArgs like this:

```
    private  void Form_MouseDown(object sender, System.WinForms.MouseEventArgs e) 
{ 
switch (e.Button) 
{ 
    case MouseButtons.Left: 
    MessageBox.Show(this,"Left Button Click"); 
    break; 
    case MouseButtons.Right: 
    MessageBox.Show(this,"Right Button Click" ); 
    break; 
    case MouseButtons.Middle: 
    break; 
    default: 
    break; 
} 

EventLog.WriteEntry("source", e.X.ToString() + " " + e.Y.ToString()); //or your own Log function

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The NunitForms test project has a recorder application that watches for this and many other events. The code is very clever and worth a good look. It's a ThoughtWorks project.

That's the rolls Royce solution though!...

Try recursively walking the Controls collection of the form and subscibe to the event based on the type.

PK :-)