# Automating Windows GUI Testing - FindWindowEx and Control Classes

Tags: c#, windows, ruby, winapi, spy++

I've inherited a C# window's application that I'm not real crazy about.  I've got a looming deadline and I'm scared to death that some of my changes might be having adverse effects on existing functionality.

I've got a hobbyist background to RoR and I'm fairly comfortable with testing in that framework (using both RSpec and Cucumber).

I love having test scripts that can be ran on a regular basis and I'm willing to spend my personal time developing those for this particular project.  I purchased a book from PragProg.com on scripted GUI testing with Ruby (http://pragprog.com/titles/idgtr/scripted-gui-testing-with-ruby).  So far, I'm digging what I'm seeing and I think that this should work well.

Unfortunately, I've got a fundamental lack of understanding concerning Windows app development.  I'm making calles to [FindWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633500(VS.85).aspx) (via Win32API) to "attempt" to retrieve sub-controls in my application.

A big part of my confusion is how I should retrieve the Class Name of the control that I'm trying to capture.  The example provided in the text is as follows:

```
    edit = find_window_ex.call @main_window, 0, 'ATL:00434310', nil
```

Where @main_window is my application's main window handle, and 'ATL:...' is the class of a text box area.  There is no explanation given as to how the author arrived at 'ATL:...'.

I've read some very old posts concerning MS's SPY++, but those seem to be obsolete (or for some reason it wasn't installed when I installed vs2010).

So, what's the best way for me to find control classes to be used with the findWindowEx call?  I do have the source code - should I be pulling from there?  What if I don't have the source code and I want to automate an application?  Is there a utility that allows you to somehow "browse" controls on a running application?

Sorry for the length - thanks in advance for the help!
Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best is for you to install the components so that you get Spy++, this is the best way I know of to get to the actual class names esp. if you do not have the source to the original controls, which might be from a library or possibly some standard ActiveX controls that Microsoft ships.

The ATL class name is probably for controls developed using [Microsoft Active Template Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ax346b7(VS.80).aspx) (ATL), this is a C++ template library which significantly simplifies the development of ActiveX controls, and COM objects etc. in C++.

Comment: So Spy++ is still a valid tool?  Great - I'll revisit the installer and see why I didn't get it with my 2010 instance.  Are there any similar stand-alone utilities that would accomplish the same thing?

-- disregard - just found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811019/i-want-spy-but-i-dont-have-visual-studio