# Capturing Win32 messages

Tags: winapi, capture, windows-messages, spy

Does anyone know a tool that can capture win32 messages that get sent to a particular process? I thought there was a tool from sysinternals for that but now I can't locate it. Anyone knows some?

Answer (score 8):

Spy++ comes with retail version of Visual Studio (Standard, Professional, Team)

See also: [I want Spy++ but I don't have Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811019/i-want-spy-but-i-dont-have-visual-studio)

Comment: It now also comes with the "community" version which is free.

Answer (score 8):

Try [WinSpy](http://www.catch22.net/software/winspy) or [Winspector](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Security-Related/Winspector.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it programmatically, you need to create a [message hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-hooks)